# readableStream unable to read, json wanted instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, get, httpresponse

I am using open source space X API and this is what my request looks like
I am wanting a json response back but it does not happen.
I am unable to read from the response which is a readableStream in ReactJS code.
However, I do see the data in dev tools in console.

```
await fetch('https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/rockets', {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-type': 'application/json', credentials: "same-origin"})
```

Answer (score 0):

const response=await fetch('https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/rockets', {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-type': 'application/json', credentials: "same-origin"})

const result=await response.json()

Try this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).